# Database design for a company: single or multi database?

Tags: database, database-design

We're (re)designing a corporate information system. For the database design, we are exploring these options:

[Option 1->] a single CompanyBigDatabase that has everything,

[Option 2->] several databases across the company (say, HRD_DB, FinanceDB, MarketingDB), which then synchronized through a layer of application. EmployeeTable is owned by HRD, if Finance wants to refer to employees, it queries EmployeeTable from HRD_DB via a web-service.

What is the best practice? What's the pros and cons? We want it to have high availability and to be reasonably reliable. Does Option 1 necessitate clustering-and-all for this? Do big companies and universities (like Toyota, Samsung, Stanford Uni, MIT, ...), always opt for Option 1?

I was looking in many DB textbooks but I could not find a sufficient explanation on this topic.

Any thoughts, tips, links, or advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: There's no one answer to this, but plenty of opinions to air!

Answer (score 3):

Ive have done this type of work for 20 yrs. Enterprise Architecting is one term used to describe this. If you are asking this question, in a real enterprise scenario, im going to recommend you get advice. If it's a uni question, There are so many things to consider:

1. budget
2. politics
3. timeframes
4. legacy systems or green field,
5. Scope of Build
6. In house or Hosted
7. Complete Outsource of some or all of the functionality (SaaS)
8. ....

**Entire Methodologies** are written to support projects that do this.
You can end up with many answers to the variables. 
Even agreeing on how to weight features and outcomes is tough.
**This is HUGE question you could right a book on.** 
Its like a 2 paragraph question where I have seen 10 people spend a month putting a business case together to do X.  Thats just costing and planning the various options. Without selection of the final approach.

> So I have not directly answered your question... that my friend is a
>   serious research project, not really a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer. It depends on the many other factors such as database load, application architecture, scalability and etc. My suggestion start the simplest way possible (single database) and change it based on the needs.

Single database has it's advantages: simpler joins, referential integrity, single backup. Only separate pieces of data when you have valid reason/need.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it would be more appropriate to have database normalized and have several databases across the company based on departments. This would allow you to manage data more effectively in terms of storing, retrieving and updating information and providing access to users based on department type or user type. You can also provide different views of the database. It will be a lot more easier to manage data.

Answer (score 0):

Either will work and other decisions will mostly affect your specification.  To some extent you question could be described as 'Should I go down the ERP path or the SAAS path"?  I think it is telling that right now most systems are tending towards SAAS.

How will you be managing the applications?  If they will be updated at different times separate DBs make more sense.  (SAAS path).  On the other hand having one DB to connect to, one authorisation system, one place to look for details, one place to backup, etc appears to decrease complexity in the technical space.  But then does not allow decisions affecting one part of the business to be considered separately from other parts of the business

Once the business is involved trying to get a single time each department agrees to an upgrade can be hell.  Having a degree of abstraction so that you only have to get one department to align before updating its part of the stack has real advantages in coming years.  And if your web services are robust and don't change with each release this can be a much easier path.

Don't forget you can have views of data in other DBs.

And as for your question of how do most big companies work; generally by a miss-mash of big and little systems that sometimes talk to each other, sometimes don't and often repeat data. Having said that repeating data is a real problem; always have an authoritative source and copies (or even better only one copy).  A method I have seen work well in a number of enterprises is to have one place details can be CRUDed (Created, Retrieved, Updated and Deleted) and numerous where it can be read.

And really this design decision has little or nothing to do with availability and reliability.  That tends to come from good design (simplicity, knowing where things live, etc) good practices (good release practices, admin practtices, backups, intelligent redundancy, etc)  and spending money.  Not from having one or multiple systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general principle of databases in particular, and computing in general, that there should be a single authoritative source for every data item.

Extending this to sets of data, as soon as you have multiple customer lists, multiple lists of items, multiple email addresses, you are soon into a quagmire of uncertainty that will then call for a business intelligence solution to resolve them all.

Now I'm a business intelligence chap by historical leaning, but I'd be the first to say that this is not a path that you want to go down simply because Marketing and Accounts cannot decide the definition of "customer". You do it because your well-normalised OLTP systems do not make it easy to count how many customers there were yesterday, last week, and last year.

Nor should they either, because then they would be in danger of sacrificing their true purpose -- to maintain a high performance, high-integrity persistent store of the "data universe" that your company exists in.

So in other words, the single database approach has data integrity on it's side, and you really do not want to work in a company that does not have data integrity. As a Business Intelligence practitioner I can tell you that it is a horrible place.

On the other hand, you are going to have practical situations in which you simply must have separate systems due to application vendor constraints etc, and in that case the problem becomes one of keeping the data as tightly coupled as possible, and of Metadata Management (ugh) in which the company agrees what data in what location has what meaning.